# How can I query which docker image is currently deployed to an app service from an azure release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have an Azure release pipeline that uses an `Azure Web App for Containers` task to deploy a docker image on an Azure App Service.

The image is specified in the form of `some_image:$(Build.BuildId)`. The pipeline works as intended and successfully updates the App Service with the latest built of the image.

I want from an other release pipeline to execute a `docker run` command using that image. I've noticed that version 1 of the `Docker` task allows me to execute such a `docker run` command on a docker image (no idea why run is missing from version 2), but how can I specify the docker image? How can I get which image is the currently deployed on that App Service?

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to do it in the same step, but this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583510/how-to-run-a-docker-container-in-azure-pipeline

Comment: I'm not trying to do it in the same step, I want to use a different pipeline for it. Unfortunately it doesn't help, I don't want to use the latest built image for the run command, I want to use the latest deployed image.

Comment: in that case you can pass the container registry and then the image name, whats difficult there

Comment: but which image version is currently deployed?

Comment: Do you need to know what is the current version deployed in Azure Web App?
Are you OK to use AZ CLI  or Powershell script to get this information?

Comment: If there's a way to use az cli or powershell in an azure release pipeline, I think it's OK

Comment: Is this documentation helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT it lists various ways except the one I'm looking for, how to do it via a release pipeline, so unfortunately it's not that helpful

Comment: @egwspiti You may add powershell script task in your pipeline to invoke Azure CLI command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session#open-ssh-session-from-remote-shell.

Answer (score 1):

Might be too late now, but what you want to do is to get the value of LinuxFXVersion (if you're running docker on Linux) property from Azure Resource Explorer.

Using a combination of Azure PowerShell and CLI, you can have these commands to retrieve the current image running on your web app:

```
 $webAppProperties = (az webapp config show --subscription "<subscription-id>" --resource-group "<resource-group-name>" -n "<webapp-name>") | ConvertFrom-Json
 $webAppProperties.linuxFXVersion
```

Assuming you have the right permissions to your subscription from Azure Pipelines, you should be able to use this information for the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use PowerShell or Shell script in the [YAML pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops). Since you already know the container registry and the image name, just use the below command to get the latest version

```
az acr repository show-tags -n MyRegistry --repository MyRepository --top 1 --orderby time_desc --detail
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository?view=azure-cli-latest#az_acr_repository_show_tags

Comment: But I don't want the latest version, I want the version that's currently deployed at the App Service

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/192684/finding-the-container-id-of-a-customer-docker-imag.html

Comment: I can ssh into my App Service container via webssh and get the deployed version but how can I do this from the release pipeline?