# How to run tests within Docker Container within Azure Pipelines? Python Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-pipelines

I want to run automated test cases against my Python Azure Functions and I want to do it in the same environment as what my actual API runs in. Thus, I want to do the testing within the Docker container. I haven't been able to find much info about this online.

My problem with what I have right now is that when I use

`docker run $(imageRepository):$(tag) pytest .`

it starts the API within my Azure Pipeline. Then it doesn't run the pytest command because that terminal is now running the local API. Is there any other way to test the API within the container within Azure Pipelines?

.yml pipeline file

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      name: $(name)
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      displayName: Checkout

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build the Docker image
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - script: |
        docker run $(imageRepository):$(tag) pytest .
      displayName: 'Run Tests'

    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
        testResultsFiles: '**/report.xml'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Push the Docker image
      inputs:
        command: push
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
      condition: succeeded()

    - task: AzureFunctionAppContainer@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        appName: '$(appName)'
        imageName: '$(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)'
      condition: succeeded()
```

This is what I see at the Run Tests step, it starts the API and then it will just sit on this step because now the API is running.

[image]

Also, I'm following this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#unit-testing) and I did see this as well [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583510/how-to-run-a-docker-container-in-azure-pipeline).